# Move .ipynb using the IPython Notebook Web Interface

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

After creating a `.ipynb` file in the root directory `/`, how can you move that `.pynb` file into a deeper directory ie: `/subdirectory` **using the web UI**?

Comment: What version are you using? Jupyter?

Comment: There is nothing even on master. you can use the in browser terminal in new > terminal

Comment: 2022 https://stackoverflow.com/a/63175447/1117305 it doesn't have a high score

Answer (score 26):

As of Sep-21 2015, there is no direct feature that supports moving files. However, there is a simple workaround. (*)

1. Select the file that you want to move.
2. Click `Rename`
3. Add the new path to the beginning of the filename.
4. Click `OK`

That's it. You should be able to find your file in the new path.

(*) https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/471

Comment: How can there not be support for moving files?  It seems like such a crucial piece of functionality.

Comment: Not working for me:Invalid notebook name. "Notebook names must have 1 or more characters and can contain any characters except :/\. Please enter a new notebook name:"

Comment: For me it works fine as well (under Win, Python 2.7). Remark: Also useful is moving upward in folder hierarchy by typing `../Filename.ipynb`

Answer (score 6):

The steps below may be an overkill to explain how to move a Jupyter notebook file from one folder to another using Jupyter. . However, it may be useful for someone who may be trying this the first time.

Let's look at an example (with example screenshots) to move "practice.py.ipynb" from "/Learn/python/puzzles" folder to "/Learn/python/puzzles/exercises" folder.

Step 1: Check the status of "practice.py.ipynv" notebook
If status is "Running" then the option to "Move" the file will not show. Follow along to "Shutdown" the notebook.
If status does not show "Running" then proceed to Step 4.

[Image link shows the status of the notebook. In our example it is "Running"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSZln.png)

Step 2: Select the notebook by clicking the checkbox next to it.
[Image link shows the options for the selected notebook. "Shutdown" is displayed as an option. Move is not an option for a running notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLIZJ.png)

Step 3: Click the "Shutdown" button for the selected notebook to stop the "Running" notebook. [Image link show the notebook is no longer running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooIIC.png)

Step 4: Select the notebook by clicking the checkbox next to it. [Image link shows the options for the selected notebook. "Move" is displayed as an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqI9N.png)

Step 5: Click "Move" button. A pop-up window is displayed with the current path (folder) of the notebook. [Image link shows current path as "/Learn/python/puzzles"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqNHq.png)

Step 6: Specify the folder where you want to move the notebook. Then click the "Move" button on the pop-up window. [Image link shows here in our example, we would like to move it to "/Learn/python/puzzles/exercises" folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc9O2.png)

File is no longer displayed in the current folder "/Learn/python/puzzles". File is no longer in the current folder. [Image link shows practice.ipynb file is not in "/Learn/python/puzzles" folder anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tyel.png)

Step 7: Click the exercises folder to navigate to "/Learn/python/puzzles/exercises" folder.
[Image link shows notebook "practice.ipynb" is moved to "/Learn/python/puzzles/exercises" folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcPtE.png)

Answer (score 4):

If some stumbles here as of 2020, it's now possible to move `.ipynb` or other kind of files by simply checking it and clicking move.

Nevertheless, for `.ipynb` files you must be sure that the notebook isn't running (gray icon). If it's running it should be green and you must shut it down before moving.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of a workaround, but you can do this:

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

1. Navigate to the directory you want to put the file in
2. Click the `Click Here`
3. Find the file and upload

Answer (score 1):

Ipython 5.1:
1. Make new folder -- with IPython running, New, Folder, select 'Untitled folder' just created, rename (and remember the name!)
2. Go to the file you want to move, Move, write new directory name at prompt
Note: If the folder exists, skip 1.
Note: If you want to leave a copy in the original directory, Duplicate and then move.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue and solved it by :

1. Create a new folder in jupyter notebooks.
2. Go to the folder/directory and click the "Upload "button which is next to the "New" button.
3. Once you click "Upload", your pc file explorer window will pop-up, now simply find where you have your jupyter notebooks saved on your local machine and upload them to that desired file/directory.

Although this doesn't technically move your python files to your desired directory, it does however make a copy in that directory. So next time you can be more organized and just click on a certain directory that you want and create/edit/view the files you chose to be in there instead of looking for them through your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the notebook and delete the original, was my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

JupyterLab (based on version 2.1.5), does not appear to have a direct move functionality (AFAICT), but does provide **yet another workaround**:

1. Right-click on the notebook file you want to move
2. Select "Cut" [image: Cut menu item]
3. Navigate to the destination folder to which you want to move it
4. Right-click in that folder (anywhere inside)
5. Select "Paste" [image: Paste menu item]

Note that the cut file doesn't immediately disappear from the original location when you cut it, but will be removed from its original location *after* pasting into the destination folder.